# jquery fadeOut doesn't do display: none;

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a project, once form is submitted 2 texts fade in and fade out. Everything works fine. but in reality fadeout just do opacity to zero. I need it to do display none;

```
$('#text-7').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
```

Under the 'text-7' there are objects that have mouse over action. After action is finished the text opacity is technically zero, not display none. so underneath objects are not hover able anymore.

Edit:

Let's say this text comes and goes after form submit

```
  <div id="storyline">
     <div id="text-6" class="justify-content-center align-items-center">
       <h1 class="text-center">Text 1</h1>
     </div>
     <div id="text-7" class="justify-content-center align-items-center">
       <h1 class="text-center">Text 2</h1>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Now, under his there is an existing object which should be hoverable. but is not, because the text-7 is blocking it.

Comment: "After action is finished the text opacity is technically zero, not display none. so underneath objects are not hover able anymore." - 0-opacity elements still have hover events, so it doesn't sound right. Can you give an example of what's happening?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I have updated an edit with example code @Kobi , but you understood me right. underneath objects are not hover able anymore. which I want them to be.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated with an html example as well

Comment: The display is set to none interally as seen in this demo. https://jsfiddle.net/4s8ytpnx/ Your problem is not related to the code shown. Or perhaps you have overwritten the `fadeOut()` method?

Comment: Please use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Please add the HTML and CSS of the object under it.

Answer (score -1):

Function fadeOut() has a callback function which is executed after the fadeOut transition.

```
$('#text-7').delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function (){
   $(this).css({ display: "none" });
});
```

Comment: This is already done internally. OP's remarks are incorrect. See the [fadout() docs](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)

Comment: It didn't work, the text is still invisibly selectable, and blocking content under it

Comment: @charlietfl is right, `.fadeOut()` should hide the element. From the docs: `The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, *the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page*.` Something else is causing it to not behave as expected.

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCodethanks for the reply, this is genuinely the only jquery in my project. I have two identical fadeOut() . only with different delays